# Having login route under /admin path in Silex

Tags: php, symfony, silex

I have Silex installation with this `SecurityServiceProvider` setup:

```
$this->app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
            'security.firewalls' => array(
                'login' => array(
                    'pattern' => '^/login$',
                ),
                'secured' => [
                    'pattern' => '^/admin.*$',
                    'anonymous' => true,
                    'form' => array(
                        'login_path' => '/login',
                        'check_path' => '/admin/auth'
                    ),
                    'logout' => array(
                        'logout_path' => '/admin/logout'
                    ),
                    'users' => $this->app->share(function() use ($self) {
                        return new AuthenticationSuccessHandler($self->app['db']);
                    }),
                ]
            ),
            'security.role_hierarchy' => [
                'ROLE_USER' => [],
                'ROLE_BACKEND_USER' => ['ROLE_USER'],
                'ROLE_SUPERADMIN' => $this->getAllBasicRoleName() 

            ],
            'security.access_rules' => array(
                ['^/.*$', 'ROLE_USER'],
                ['^/admin.*$', 'ROLE_SUPERADMIN'],
                ['^/admin.*$', 'ROLE_BACKEND_USER']
            )
        ));
```

This setup resolve:

```
/login -> login form
/admin -> secure area
/admin/logout -> logout form
```

But I need login form to be reachable under admin path like this:

```
/admin/login -> login form UNDER ADMIN PATH!
/admin -> secure area
/admin/logout -> logout form
```

There is a way to do this?

Thanks.
S.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried changing:
`'login_path' => '/login',` to `'login_path' => '/admin/login',` ?

I think you will also want to change `'pattern'=> '^/login$',` to  `'pattern'=> /admin(.*)`